# quokka with angular in Intellij tsconfig.json not found

Tags: angular8, angular-test, quokka.js

I have angular 8 project with typescript and jest for running tests. I am trying to configure quokka to run in IntelliJ.

I installed quokka plugin in IntelliJ with empty .quokka.json, I don't understand why example in quokka configuration is referencing to babel I am not using babel so I am assuming I don't need any configuration in .quokka.json.

[Quokka configuration](https://quokkajs.com/docs/configuration.html#quokka-file-config)

in IntelliJ when I run my basic .spec.ts I gets following error.

```
Cannot find module @angular/http'
```

and at the bottom it is complaining

```
could not find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped.
```

I have tsconfig.json on root where I have package.json and .quokka.json file. wondering if there is a way to tell quokka where to look for tsconfig and node_modules.

not very happy with quokka configuration documentation but I am willing to give it a try if some one help me out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i reached out to company who wrote this they told me quokka is only simple javascript, for angular we have to use wallaby plugin instead.